# Grails cannot cast JSON array to HashMap

Tags: json, grails, groovy, hashmap

I have the following JSON (stored as a String in Groovy):

```
{
    "isFizz": "true",
    "buzzProperties": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "widget": 35
        }
    ],
    "name": "dummy1"
}
```

In my Grails controller I have the following method that handles this JSON as an HTTP request and attempts to read the JSON into Groovy vars:

```
Stuff register() {  
    def jsonObject = request.JSON
    Stuff stuff = new Stuff()
    stuff.isFizz                    = jsonObject.isFizz
    stuff.buzzProperties            = jsonObject.buzzProperties             // stuff.buzzProperties is a HashMap
    stuff.name                      = jsonObject.name

    stuff
}
```

When the controller method executes (when it receives a request) I get the following exception:

```
Cannot cast object '[{"foo":"bar"},{"widget":35}]' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject). Stacktrace follows:
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[{"foo":"bar"},{"widget":35}]' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject)
```

I checked the JSON against [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it is perfectly valid JSON. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind the fact that `buzzProperties` is not a `Map` it's a `List` (`{}` vs `[]`). That's why the casting cannot be proceed. Either change the `buzzProperties` type to `List` or send a valid `Map`.

**EDIT**

The json string you send should be defined in the following way:

```
{
    "isFizz": "true",
    "buzzProperties": {
       "foo": "bar",
       "widget": 35
    },
    "name": "dummy1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - I can't (easily) change the Grails controller, but can easily alter the JSON. What would the `buzzProperties` object need to look like in the JSON in order to be a valid map?

Comment: If you want to stick to the list of maps, you can also flatten this with something like this `jsonObject.buzzProperties.sum()`

Comment: @cfrick bad idea if you have items in the list with same keys. It should be a json object in the first place.

Comment: Another option that lets you retain `buzzProperties` as a `Map` in `Stuff` and retain the list-of-maps format coming back from the server is to add a setter for that - `void setBuzzProperties(List props) { ... }`. Loop through each one and set the values one at a time. The Groovy compiler should still generate `void setBuzzProperties(Map props) { ... }` and `Map getBuzzProperties() { ... }` but be sure that that's the case (e.g. with JD-GUI) and add that setter explicitly if needed.